# Devolver una cadena pasada como argumento a una funcion

Tags: c

tengo este code y el problema es que solo me imprime una h

> Code

```
#include <stdio.h>

char imprimir_cadena(const char *cadena2);

int main(){

   const char *ptr="hola";

   const char *p=imprimir_cadena(ptr);

   printf("%s",&p);

   return 0;

}

char imprimir_cadena(const char *cadena2){

    return *cadena2; //el asterico * es opcional?


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Porque estás mostrando el valor que apunta el puntero, el 1er caracter de tu cadena en este caso.

Deberías iterar sobre la cadena hasta hasta que p apunte a 0, que es el valor con que finaliza las cadenas C.

Comment: No comprendo bien

Answer (score 0):

Gracias a MAFUS por ayudarme con mis dudas en este maravilloso lenguaje
Aqui dejo la respuesta de MAFUS, espero que a alguien le sirva

```
#include <stdio.h>

char* imprimir_cadena(const char *cadena2);

int main(){
    const char *ptr="hola";
    const char *p=imprimir_cadena(ptr);
    printf("%s", p); // cuando se imprimen cadenas no se usa asterisco
    return 0;
}

char* imprimir_cadena(const char *cadena2){ // nota que el tipo de dato devuelto es char*
    return cadena2; //el asterico * es opcional? No, no debe estar
}
```

Comment: C de maravilloso no tiene nada.